# Routes with param id not working for prerender in Angular 17 SSR

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, prerender, angular17

I use Angular 17 with SSR. My main goal for using SSR is to use `Meta from "@angular/platform-browser"` for showing prerender info with replacing tags on `facebook` during creat post. Everything works good. But not with route where I have a param: id

I found the documentation for prerender routes with param on official [official website](https://angular.dev/guide/prerendering)

All I need it add each route manually to `routes.txt` in `angular.json`

```
"prerender": {
          "routesFile": "src/assets/routes.txt"
        },
```

I added for testing two routes with param to this file

```
/encyclopedia/persons/157151314
/encyclopedia/persons/425922380
```

And in result I have this routes after build in my `dist/prerendered-routes.json`

```html
{
  "routes": [
    "/",
    "/contacts",
    "/encyclopedia",
    "/encyclopedia/history",
    "/encyclopedia/persons",
    "/encyclopedia/persons/157151314",
    "/encyclopedia/persons/425922380",
    "/encyclopedia/photos",
    "/memory",
    "/support"
  ]
}
```

When I load this route `/encyclopedia/persons` my replacing metatags works good

```
setCeoSettings() {
const pageUrl = 'https://my-web-site/encyclopedia/persons';
this.metaService.updateMetaTags({
  title: response.Title,
  type: 'article',
  imageSrc: response.CoverPhoto,
  url: pageUrl,
  description: response.Description,
  cardType: 'summary_large_image',
});
}
```

For example in `/encyclopedia/persons` there are 3 api-call to server and I put my `setCeoSettings()` function after response in one of them

```
getPaginationMemory(publish: boolean, pageNumber: number, push: boolean): void {
this.debounceSpiner = true;
const params = this.buildParam(publish, pageNumber)
this.personService.getPagination(params).subscribe(
  (suc: string) => {
    this.personResponse = deserialize(PaginationGeneric<Person>, suc);
    this.personResponse.Items.forEach(elemet =>
      this.persons.push(elemet));
    this.setCeoSettings(); //<--- here 
    this.debounceSpiner = false;
    this.debounceSpinnerLoadMorePerson = false;
  },
  () => {
    this.debounceSpiner = false;
  });
```

}

And it works good. My tags in prerender during creating post on facebook works good. I see cover photo from response and all other information on facebook post.

But when I create post with this route `/encyclopedia/persons/157151314` I have a problem. I see on facebook in prerender my metatags from `index.html` page. Not from my `setCeoSettings()` with response information

In both cases I make my api call from `ngOnInit()`

Part of my `AppRoutingModule`

```html
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'encyclopedia', component: EncyclopediaComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'encyclopedia/persons', component: PersonsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'encyclopedia/persons/:id', component: PersonComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'encyclopedia/history', component: HistoryComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'encyclopedia/history/:id', component: HistoryViewComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}

Any idias how to fix it?
```